# Potentially diagonal $K$-algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

In our abstract algebra class, we had two lectures on field extensions. Then we were given the following homework problem (with [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1719184/equivalent-conditions-for-diagonal-k-algebra) on diagonal $K$-algebra).

Let $K$ be a field. A commutative $K$-algebra $A$ such that $[A:K]$ is finite and $A$ is isomorphic to $K^X$ where $|X|=n$ is called a diagonal $K$-algebra.

A commutative $K$-algebra $A$ is said to be potentially diagonal if there exists an extension $L$ of $K$ such that $L \otimes_K A$ is a diagonal $L$-algebra.

There are two questions.

1) Let $\Omega$ be an algebraic closure of $K$. Let $P(X) \neq 0$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ in $K[X]$, and let $A = K[X]/(P(X))$. Assume $P(X)$ has $n$ distinct roots in $\Omega$. Show that $A$ is potentially diagonal.

2) Let $B$ and $C$ be potentially diagonal algebras, and let $A = B \otimes_K C$. Show that $A$ is potentially diagonal.

I am really lost as to how to solve these two questions. Any help/ hint/ comment is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1)

- Show that $\Omega\otimes_KA$ is isomorphic to the $\Omega$-algebra $\Omega[X]/(P(X))$.
- Since $P$ has no repeated factor, it admits a factorization $P(X)=\prod_{i=1}^n(X-\omega_i)$ with the $\omega_1,\dots,\omega_n$ are pairwise distinct elements of $\Omega$. Use the Chinese remainder theorem to show that $\Omega[X]/(P(X))$ is isomorphic to the diagonal algebra $\Omega^n$.

For 2)

- Show that $A$ is a potentially diagonal $K$-algebra if and only if $\Omega\otimes_KA$ is a diagonal algebra.
- Show that $\Omega\otimes_K(A\otimes_KB)$ is isomorphic to $(\Omega\otimes A)\otimes_\Omega(\Omega\otimes_KB)$.
- Use these two facts to conclude that the tensor product of two potentially diagonal algebras is potentially diagonal.